# PHP convert all instances of plain text URL, video and image references to HTML

Tags: php, html, text, converters, autolink

I was wondering if anyone knew a PHP function that could take some plain text, and convert any urls to links, any image urls to image tags and any video urls to embedded videos as appropriate.

For example

> www.mywebsite.com is the name of my site and this is the logo www.mywebsite.com/logo.jpg I have a video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loab4A_SqoQ

Would result in

```
<a href=“www.mywebsite.com”>www.mywebsite.com</a> is the name of my site and this is the logo <img src=“www.mywebsite.com/logo.jpg” /> I have a video at <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/loab4A_SqoQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: How the software is supposed to tell that the string pattern of _"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loab4A_SqoQ"_ is actually a video?

Comment: It would need to detect that youtube pattern just as I would anything in an image file extension.

Comment: well, you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30108346/3709765) useful, just some very easy refinements may be necessary.